# Every monotone mapping between posets is also a simplicial mapping on their order complexes

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics, algebraic-topology

This is Proposition 1.7.3 in Matoušek's "Using the Borsuk-Ulam Theorem":

> Every monotone mapping $f:P_1 \to P_2$ between posets is also a simplicial mapping $V(\Delta(P_1)) \to V(\Delta(P_2))$ between their order complexes.

It is an exercise to prove this proposition, and I wanted to see if I have the right idea, and if there are any other or easier ways to prove this statement.

Here are the definitions used in the text:

> Let $(P_1, \leq_1), (P_2, \leq_2)$ be posets. A mapping $f:P_1\to P_2$ is *monotone* if $x_1 \leq_1 x_2$ implies $f(x_1) \leq_2 f(x_2)$.
>
> A *simplicial mapping* from a complex $K$ to a complex $L$ is a map $f:V(K)\to V(L)$ (on their vertices) such that $f(\sigma)\in L$ whenever $\sigma \in K$.

My idea for a proof: Since simplices in the order complex correspond to chains (i.e., linearly ordered subsets), to show that $f$ is also a simplicial map it suffices to check that a chain $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k\}$ in $P_1$ gets sent to a chain $\{f(x_1), f(x_2), \dots, f(x_k)\}$ in $P_2$. I think one could verify this using induction on the length of the chain. Is this correct?

Also, are there other ways to prove this (e.g., categorically)?